# Need advice on how to do this in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Is this possible to do this in one MySQL query? Basically I need to sort users by how many responses they have. I have 2 tables

```
table "users":
id      username
------------------
1       hunter
2       loserville
```

and another

```
table "responses":
id      user_id     response
-------------------------------
1         1            yes
1         2            yes
1         1            no
1         1            yes
```

I need something like this

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT COUNT(responses.id) As num_responses
        FROM responses
        WHERE user_id = users.id
ORDER BY num_responses DESC
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Any suggestions? Let me know if you are confused! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, count(*) as responses
FROM   users LEFT JOIN responses
       ON users.Id = responses.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.username
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
SELECT  u.id, COUNT(r.id) AS cnt
FROM    users u
LEFT JOIN
        responses r
ON      r.user_id = u.id
        AND r.response = 'yes'
GROUP BY
        u.id
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
```

or this:

```
SELECT  u.id,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    responses r
        WHERE   r.user_id = u.id
                AND r.response = 'yes'
        ) cnt
FROM    users u
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
```

The former is generally faster in `InnoDB`, the latter in `MyISAM`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to use is the GROUP BY clause.

You'd want a query like

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(*) AS responses 
    FROM users JOIN responses ON users.id = responses.user_id 
    GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY responses DESC
```

(if you don't want any information from the users table, you can leave out the JOIN and only do the query on the responses.

The join lists all users with their responses and then counts the number of entries.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I had to do a LEFT JOIN and that worked for me

Comment: That is true, the left join will also list people that haven't made any responses. However, I'm not sure if COUNT(*) will work correctly then. It might list 1 response instead of 0 for users that haven't posted.